# a tag closing before it should

Tags: html, css, jscript

Below is a syntax html i have written for my project. I don't think anything is wrong with my code. however browser compiles it differently.

My code:

```html
<a href="#" class="m-news">
  <div class="mn-title">
  </div>
  <div class="mn-content">
  </div>
  <div class="news-footer">
    <a href="#"></a>
  </div>
</a>
```

How browser is compiling it:

Can anyone tell me why is this happening? I did the removing js, removing css,a nd all other possible tests.i tested in opera internet explorer chrome .

Comment: There is no proper explanation of your Question

Comment: Sorry, some how all code were not uploaded properly in the question. probably my fault.

How browser is compiling my code.

<a href="#" class="m-news">
 <div class="mn-title">
 </div>
 <div class="mn-content">
 </div>
</a>
<div class="news-footer">
 <a href="#" class="m-news">
 </a>
</div>

Comment: As you can see a tag closes before the div tag with "news-footer class. I have no proper way to explain this. can some one help?

Comment: well, there is no logic to put link isinde another link and thus this is illegal

Answer (score 4):

It is forbidden to nest `<a>` elements.

The second `<a>` start tag is ignored, and the first `</a>` end tag, therefore, closes the first `<a>`.

If you had [used a validator](https://validator.nu), it would have picked up this error.

Comment: I need the entire section to be an a tag including a tag within the div. how do you suggest i do it?

Comment: @ArsMileYan check link of duplicates to get more details ;)